# reCaptcha not validating on server side

Tags: php, recaptcha

I have used reCaptcha control. The Problem is that the Captcha is not validating itself, i have wrote a validating code i.e.,

```
require_once('recaptchalib.php');
$privatekey = "my key";
$resp = recaptcha_check_answer ($privatekey,
        $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
        $_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"],
        $_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]);

if (!$resp->is_valid) {
 $errCapt='<p style="color:#D6012C ">The CAPTCHA Code wasnot entered correctly.</p>';  }
```

Even if i put the wrong code , it goes on..

Please help

Comment: What do you do after that if? header() to somewhere or exit?

Comment: Does setting `$errCapt` do something to stop submission in your code?

Comment: There is no Else part, just headers and mail function..

Comment: Yes $errCapt, shows error when the form is empty, and i click submit. http://team-kh.hireexpertprogrammers.com/~maiarn/EmailForm.php Please have a look there

Comment: This is not working on Server side, at localhost it work fine...

Answer (score 0):

Check your domain name in recaptcha account.

Is it global or for single site?

Do you have more than one site?

Check fsocket function exists and it is enable in your host or not. (check in phpinfo page).

Comment: recaptcha is for global domain. I have only one site for which i am using this. And fsocket doesnot appear in phpinfo page